# does postgresql jdbc driver has \copy?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

as stated,

does java jdbc driver for postgresql has client side \copy?

I wanted to do batch inserts into a table in the database on a remote machine with data from my text file on another machine.

Comment: @Harry, I need to do inserts into the database but the file is only my client machine...

Comment: you mean file is only on client machine. Which file? database backup file?

Comment: I wanted to do batch inserts into a table in the database on a remote machine with data from my text file on another machine.

Comment: what you can do is: 1) Configure postgres for remote machine. 2) read file from client machine. 3)Execute queries listed on file.

Answer (score 9):

Since the 8.4 driver there is support for the COPY command, through the CopyManager:

http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html

Answer (score 0):

add ip of your system from where you used to update database in pg_hba.conf file
connect usinyg url

```
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database
```

execute query