# CSV not getting imported with COPY

Tags: jdbc, postgresql-9.1

I was trying to import CSV into PostgreSQL using JDBC.
I'm using this command:

```
sql ="\\copy data1_1 from 'C:\\Users\\legolas\\Desktop\\data1.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV";
```

But nothing gets written to the table. I'm not getting any errors.
When I use the same command in the `psql` shell everything works perfectly.

I'm working on windows.

Comment: How do you execute the sql statement ? Do you get any error code (that does not imply to get an error message on screen) ?

Answer (score 1):

The command you are trying to send is start with `\copy`. Every "command" starting with `\` is *NOT* an SQL command but something the `psql` shell handles by itself. Therefore you cannot `\copy` in JDBC.

You *can* use the SQL variant `copy`. But since `copy` is a PostgreSQL special you have to fiddle with some driver internals. As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726362/does-postgresql-jdbc-driver-has-copy) states, the entry point for that is the class `CopyManager` wich is "documented" [here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html). In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958965/how-to-copy-a-data-from-file-to-postgresql-using-jdbc) there is even a working example.