# Issue with exporting portgresql table to CSV in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, csv

I'm using postgresql to host my database. In my database, I have a table say xyz whose structure is as shown below

```
id    content    folder
1     hello      Inbox
2     hi         Sent
```

I want to export this table to CSV using my java program. The code snippet is below

```
Connection connection2  = new ServerDBConnect().getConnection();
PreparedStatement statement = connection2.prepareStatement("copy (SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE folder=? ) to 'C:/export.csv' delimiter ','");
statement.setString(1, FOLDER_SELECTED); //Here, FOLDER_SELECTED=Inbox
statement.execute();
```

When I execute this code, I'm getting `SQLException` saying

```
ERROR: there is no parameter $1
```

If I execute the code without folder specified (`"copy (SELECT * FROM xyz) to 'C:/export.csv' delimiter ','")`), the code works fine.

What am I doing wrong here? How to go about this problem?

Note: If I execute the query (`copy (SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE folder='Inbox' ORDER BY time) to 'G:/export.csv' delimiter ','`) directly in the Postgresql SQL console, I'm getting the desired output.

Please help

Comment: Not sure if this question is relevant to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726362/does-postgresql-jdbc-driver-has-copy

Comment: @AndreaPolci: thanks, but that link is of no relevance to me. I'm trying to export the content of a table in my local database to my local system

Comment: Looks relevant to me. The link is to a question asking how to use `copy` from JDBC.

Comment: @skaffman: Using `copy` is not a problem to me, but I'm not able to specify the filter (`folder='Inbox'`) in the query

Comment: You are not really using a sql statement in the prepared statement, you are using some psql command. I'm surprised it even works without a bind. I believe the proper way to do it is with CopyManager as shown in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958965/how-to-copy-a-data-from-file-to-postgresql-using-jdbc (and I think the other comments are relevant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah

I finally found the answer myself.

Small change in the query gave me the desired result

The query is suppose to be like this

```
Connection connection2  = new ServerDBConnect().getConnection();
PreparedStatement statement = connection2.prepareStatement("copy (SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE folder='" + FOLDER_SELECTED + "' ) to 'C:/export.csv' delimiter ','");
```

This was driving me crazy, but finally done :-)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for future readers:
Only do this if `FOLDER_SELECTED` comes from a trusted source. Otherwise, you will be vulnerable to SQL injection.